# POST an array with similar names and similar values

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am posting this because I do not really know what I could search for. Please note that I have basic knowledges and am still learning ; also, I might sometimes use wrong terms, sorry about that.

I am setting up a web application through PHP/MySQL, HTML, Bootstrap, and JQuery.

I need to post an array to my database. The problem is, this array might contain several times the same value. Indeed, the array is made out of values inside a html table, to which rows can be added to add more data at the same time thanks to JQuery and DataTable.

So far, I did not even know how to post an array, and found the following solution to be working to do so, as the following code:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input name="country[]" value="France">
    <input name="country[]" value="Spain">
    <input name="country[]" value="Germany">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```php
$country = $_POST['country'];
print_r $country;
```

Would contain the following array result:

```
|country|
|-------|
|France |
|Spain  |
|Germany|
```

Wonderful.

But what I need to do sometimes, is something like this:

```html
<form method="post">
    <input name="country[]" value="France">
    <input name="country[]" value="France">
    <input name="country[]" value="France">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I would like this:

```php
$country = $_POST['country'];
print_r $country;
```

To contain the array:

```
|country|
|-------|
|France |
|France |
|France |
```

But instead, the POST contains only

```
|country|
|-------|
|France |
```

Whereas Firefox Developer Tools clearly indicates me that the page sent the exact array I need to receive.

```
Form Data
   country[]: [...]
      0: France
      1: France
      2: France
```

Could you please help me with that?
Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: How are you checking what `$_POST['country'];` contains?

Comment: why 3 times  the same name value for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Daan for asking me how I checked what `$_POST['country'];` contains.

I modified my original post to include these information. By doing so, I saw that I checked it once I changed it, as I use it again later in a foreach, to display all the rows in another array.

So I checked it the right way.

It turned out my problem was a lot more different, and is related to my use of the foreach.

Indeed, I use the country name as an index for the foreach. As it can only use unique indexes, it uses only once "France".

To scaisEdge: This is data I modified to be anonymous, and country was the easiest way to do so. Imagine products instead of countries, and this is why the user can add several times one unique name.